# Como remover as tags img de um texto?

Tags: javascript

Preciso remover todas as tag de img do texto em javascript. Para que as imagens não venham.
Obs: O texto é aleatório.

Como_vai_estar:

```
Vestibulum varius lectus a ante euismod <img src="teste2.jpg"> cursus. Nam sed semper augue, a laoreet purus. <img src="teste.jpg"> Vivamus ut risus eu lectus imperdiet sollicitudin.
```

Como_deve_ficar:

```
Vestibulum varius lectus a ante euismod cursus. Nam sed semper augue, a laoreet purus. Vivamus ut risus eu lectus imperdiet sollicitudin.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podes usar um elemento temporário para limpar isso.

Eu costumo fazer assim:

```js
function limparHTML(html) {
  const proxy = document.createElement('div');
  proxy.innerHTML = html;
  return proxy.innerText;
}

const HTML = 'Vestibulum varius lectus a ante euismod <img src="teste2.jpg"> cursus. Nam sed semper augue, a laoreet purus. <img src="teste.jpg"> Vivamus ut risus eu lectus imperdiet sollicitudin.';

const limpo = limparHTML(HTML);
alert(limpo);
```

Se estiveres em ambiente Node.js ou não puderes usar elementos como sugeri, podes tentar com RegExp.

Nesse Caso poderia ser assim:

```js
function limparHTML(html) {
  return html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
}

const HTML = 'Vestibulum varius lectus a ante euismod <img src="teste2.jpg"> cursus. Nam sed semper augue, a laoreet purus. <img src="teste.jpg"> Vivamus ut risus eu lectus imperdiet sollicitudin.';

const limpo = limparHTML(HTML);
alert(limpo);
```

A idea de `/<img[^>]+>/g` é:

- tem de ter a string `<img`
- depois da string (em cima) `[^>]*` quer dizer "qualquer caractere, excluíndo o `>` zero ou mais vezes"
- finalizar com o caractere `>``
- `g` quer dizer "globalmente", em todas as ocorrências

<sub>**Nota:** Na primeira versão da minha resposta com regex tinha `[^>]+`, mas mudei para `*`, zero ou mais vezes, e [que o Randrade sugeriu primeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201283/129), pois pode haver casos de tags só com `<img>`</sub>

Comment: Poxa, 1seg... Vou deixar só a sua que estar mais completa :p

Comment: @Randrade deixa estar, mereces `+1` até porque usas `*` que é melhor que `+`. E eu vou corrigir para tb usar `*`

Comment: Tudo bem então xD

Answer (score 5):

Você também pode utilizar a seguinte expressão para isso:

```
var textoConvertido = html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var html = 'Vestibulum varius lectus a ante euismod <img src="teste2.jpg"> cursus. Nam sed semper augue, a laoreet purus. <img src="teste.jpg"> Vivamus ut risus eu lectus imperdiet sollicitudin.';
var textoConvertido = html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');

console.log(textoConvertido);
```